# How to get resized image from PDF vector asset?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uiimageview, vector-graphics, sktexture

I am developing game with SpriteKit for iPhone devices only. 
In the scene I have buttons, which need to be positioned in the way to fill the height of the screen:

[image]

There should be no gaps between top and bottom edges, as well as from each other. The width can vary. Buttons contains vector ornaments, done in AI.

In order to achieve that, I thought I could use PDF asset, set to "single scale" and "Preserve Vector Data". Then I thought I can get slightly resized PNG file out of PDF and reposition then based on client area. However, it appears `SKTextureNode` doesn't take PDF as source. I get blurry image.

The code for loading image:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyButton")
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: 81*4, height: 165*4)) // PDF size is 81x165
```

This works just fine with `UIImageView`, where you can set any size and it will give you crisp image. I can guess that there is some magic routine somewhere in `UIImageView`, which forces to create new image of given size.
So my question is whether there is a way to engage this magic routine for SpriteKit?

Comment: Why do you want to load a texture from a PDF file? Why can't you store it as a PNG file?

Comment: @KugelnMMXVI With PDF I store single file. With PNG I have to store image for every device. It's hell lot of assets. I would do it if the image content would have been different for each device. But they are same, just size is slightly different.

Comment: Have you changed the "Scale Factors" parameter in Xcode for this file? Also try to load "BuyButton@2x" instead of "BuyButton".

Comment: @KugelnMMXVI yes, it is set to Single Scale.

Comment: What about load as UIImage and after initializate SKTexture with image instead imagenamed?

Comment: @Simone Pistecchia: I've tried that and unfortunately the image is still blurry. This gives me a hint that the actual conversion from PDF to PNG takes place in `UIImageView`, which I am not using.

Comment: Have you considered using svg instead of pdf, and then using a library like svgkit to load it? https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

Comment: @Sune I would like first to make sure that there is no native solution. Using 3rd party libraries is last resort.

Comment: PDF rasterization only happens in UIKit from what I remember,  in sprite kit, it will treat your original image size as the 1x image and perform basic scaling.  I would recommend you go from PDF -> UIImageView and generate your asset at the desired scale, then take the UIImages from the view and place them into an SKTextureAtlas for you to grab in the future

Comment: @Knight0fDragon but how to do it off-screen?

Comment: Create a new uiimageview of the specific size you need